# @font-face works for all browsers but one

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts

I have a custom font set up like so in the css:

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: 'FinkRoman';  
  src: url( /fonts/FinkRoman.eot ); /* IE */  
  src: local("FinkRoman"), url( /fonts/FinkRoman.ttf ) format("truetype"); 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I am testing the site in several browsers and it displays fine in all but one:

Macbook Retina Firefox - OK

Macbook Retina Safari - OK

Macbook Retina Chrome - OK

Macbook Pro Safari - OK

Macbook Pro Firefox - defaults to Times

I checked the Firefox settings in the Macbook Pro and in the advanced font settings, it is checked to allow pages to choose their own fonts. But for some reason it just doesn't work here. I have no idea why. This font was chosen and purchased by my client. Any ideas why this wouldn't work. What is even weirder is that my Macbook Retina and Pro both have the same version of Firefox (the latest). The Pro is using an older OS (Snow Leopard) but that shouldn't matter. Ever seen this?

Comment: Any errors in the error console?

Comment: There it is. It was rejected by Firefox's sanitizer on my Pro, but not in any of the other browsers on this laptop or on my other laptop. Weird. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: done, but now we've just replaced one mystery with another...  I didn't think the font sanitizer depended on the OS in any way.  You said you're using Firefox 16.0.2 on both machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this it's always worth checking the error console: failures to do  cross-site loads or sanitize the font will be logged there.

What I don't know offhand is why either one of those would behave differently on your Macbook Retina and Macbook Pro, in the same Firefox version...